# List most recent videos from Youtube channels, code works but Youtube Data API daily quota fills up WAY too fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, youtube, youtube-data-api

My code below works, but **why does it fill up the Youtube Data API's daily quota (10k queries) really fast?**

I'm a total javascript noob and I can't work it out. Every refresh of a browser seems to make 200+ queries.

The **idea of the code** is that when browser is refreshed, it looks up 10 most recent videos from the Youtube channel IDs listed in `youtubeChannels`, and then shows each channel's videos in their respective divs (".youtube1", ".youtube2").

```
var key = 'XXX';

youtubeChannels = {
    "youtube1": "UCnVzApLJE2ljPZSeQylSEyg",
    "youtube2": "UCCezIgC97PvUuR4_gbFUs5g",
}

Object.keys(youtubeChannels).forEach(function (item) {     
    divId = item; // for example "youtube1"
    var channelId = youtubeChannels[item]; // for example "UCnVzApLJE2ljPZSeQylSEyg"
    var URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search';
    var options = {
        part: 'snippet',
        key: key,
        maxResults: 10,
        channelId: channelId,
        order: 'date'
        }

    youtubeVideos(URL, options, divId);
});

function youtubeVideos(URL, options, divId) {      
    $.getJSON(URL, options, function(data){       
    for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {            
        var id = data.items[i].snippet.title;
        var videoId = data.items[i].id.videoId;
        var videoUrl = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${videoId}`;
        var titleLink = `<a href='${videoUrl}'>${id}</a>`;
        document.querySelector(`.${divId}`).innerHTML += `${titleLink}<br>`;
    }
})}
```

I suspect it's something to do with the forEach line, but it's my first javascript project so can't fully understand what's causing this. Any help would be appreciated, I assume that this functionality shouldn't reach the 10 000 query limit this fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the issue was not with the code per se, but that querying Youtube API's "search" endpoint actually has a quota cost of 100 units per query.

I modified the code to query the API's "playlistitems" endpoint instead, which only has a cost of 1 unit, and now the problem is solved.